# Permanently disable Auto Preview in views?

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to make views stop defaulting to Auto Preview on? It's really slowing down my workflow.

Answer (score 14):

As seems to always be the case, I stumbled upon the views settings page after posting the question: On admin/structure/views/settings unselect "Automatically update preview on changes."

[image: screenshot]

Comment: LIFE SAVER!!! I had some erroneous javascript that was killing me